# How to write Shared preference Code that uses firebase for User authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences

How do I write Shared-preference Code that is using Firebase for User authentication and the data that is saved by a user is only accessible for them?
My current application Saves a note and displays it which is the main thing needed in my project but when a user logs out and new user logs in he/she can also view the data so the data is not private. My sir suggested to make nodes for users using shared preference but i couldn't find any solutions

HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Descriptionholder;
    Button Savebtn;
    DatabaseReference DatabaseNote;
    ListView listViewNotes;

    List<PrivateNote> privateNoteList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        DatabaseNote = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("privatenote");
        Descriptionholder = findViewById(R.id.description2);

        Savebtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonsave);

        listViewNotes= findViewById(R.id.listViewPrivate);

        privateNoteList = new ArrayList<>();
        Savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                addnote();
            }

        });

        listViewNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                PrivateNote privateNote = privateNoteList.get(i); //confusion

                showUpdateDialog(privateNote.getNoteId(),privateNote.getNoteDescription());
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.side, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item1:

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    finish();

                    startActivity(new Intent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)));
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseNote.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        privateNoteList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot privateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

                    PrivateNote privateNote = privateSnapshot.getValue(PrivateNote.class);

                    privateNoteList.add(privateNote);
                }
             PrivateList adapter = new PrivateList(HomeActivity.this,privateNoteList);
                listViewNotes.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showUpdateDialog(final String noteId, String noteDescription){

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialouge,null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogview);

        final  EditText editDescription = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.editDescription);
        final Button buttonUpdate = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        final Button buttonDelete = dialogview.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Updating Note: " +noteDescription);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String description = editDescription.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(description)){
                    editDescription.setError(" New information required");
                    return;
                }
                    updatePrivateNote(noteId,description);

                    alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                deletePrivateNote(noteId);
            }
        });
    }

    private void deletePrivateNote(String noteId) {

        DatabaseReference drPrivateNote = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("privatenote").child(noteId);

        drPrivateNote.removeValue();

        Toast.makeText(this, " Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private boolean updatePrivateNote(String id,String description){

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("privatenote").child(id);

        PrivateNote privateNote = new PrivateNote(id,description);

        databaseReference.setValue(privateNote);

        Toast.makeText(this, " Note Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    private void addnote () {

            String description = Descriptionholder.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(description)){

                //generated unique number for id
                String id = DatabaseNote.push().getKey();

                PrivateNote pNote = new PrivateNote(id, description);

                DatabaseNote.child(id).setValue(pNote); //pNote value added in id
                Toast.makeText(this, "Note added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else {

                Toast.makeText(this, " Please Enter a note ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        finish();


                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class PrivateList  extends ArrayAdapter<PrivateNote> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<PrivateNote> privateNoteList;



    public PrivateList(Activity context, List<PrivateNote> privateNoteList){

                super(context, R.layout.list_layout,privateNoteList);
                this.context =context;
                this.privateNoteList=privateNoteList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null,true);

        TextView textViewDescription = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDescription);

        PrivateNote privateNote = privateNoteList.get(position);

        textViewDescription.setText(privateNote.getNoteDescription());

        return listViewItem;

    }

}
```

PrivateNote:

```
public class PrivateNote {

   public String noteId;
    public String noteDescription;

    public PrivateNote(){

    }

    PrivateNote(String noteId, String noteDescription){

        this.noteId = noteId;
        this.noteDescription=noteDescription;
    }



    String getNoteId()
    {
        return noteId;
    }

    String getNoteDescription()
    {
        return noteDescription;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you store in `SharedPreferences` and not directly in the database?

Comment: I stored in Fire-base real-time Database but the information is not private for a particular user, it can be seen by every user who logs in so i asked my sir who suggested me to use shared preference and make nods of user but i don't know how

Comment: It is not private if you do not secure it. You should use [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) for that and everything will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your solution I will implement that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I only have one table NOTE does that effect the Access ?

Comment: Doesn't matter how many nodes you have.

Comment: I have these in my rules{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: You rules allow everybody to read and write, you should secure it.

Comment: How can I secure it?

Comment: See the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, there are two things,

1. `FirebaseDatabase`
2. `FirebaseAuth`

Usually, in almost all the apps, user data is stored in the `FirebaseDatabase` under the key, that is generated while creating a new user in your Firebase app.

So, for example, your database structure will look like this.

```
-Your_main_database

 |____UserId_Of_FirebaseUser

      |____stuff_related_to_user

      |____More stuff related to user
```

So, you create a new user in `FirebaseAuth`, you can find more about it below:

[Firebase Custom Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

Then, after creating a new user, you create child nodes under your database with the key=userId of your current logged in user.

eg. In your addNote function, the `id` variable will be equal to

```
String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Currently, you're using Push keys which are generated based on Timestamp, which you won't be able to associate with user unless you add a key inside your note object which stored current username, and then find all the child nodes that contain that username, but in that case, your data won't be organized at all.

Then, after you create a node with userId under your main database, you can then push new notes created by your user inside the userId with the `push()` function. So your database structure will look like below.

```
___
   |
   |__users
           |__uniqueUserId
           |              |__note1
           |              |__note2
           |__uniqueUserId2
                          |__note1
                          |__note2
                          |__note3
```

Next time whenever you want to fetch user created notes, you log in the user, get his ID, and then find the notes corresponding to that ID.

I don't see how you can fit `SharedPreferences` in there, before there is also function to cache data offline in Firebase once it is loaded.

**Securing the notes:**

If you implement the database like I said above, you'll be very easily able to secure your database.

[Common Database Rules](https://gist.github.com/codediodeio/6dbce1305b9556c2136492522e2100f6).

If you implement everything correctly like I told, you'll be able to secure your database with the fourth set of rules from above rules.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. So do I need to redo my code? I don't know how to make child-nodes. I have only a Single table in my database named Private Note that stores a unique id and the note .

Comment: Instead of generating random push keys in your addNote() function, create a child note with unique userid, and then push the new notes under that userId

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using firebase authentication, then you can retrieve the `userId`, and create the following database:

```
notes
  userId
      note        : "todo"
      description : "study"
```

Then you can do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notes");
FirebaseUser user     = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId         = user.getUid();
ref.orderByKey().equalTo(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

This way you would retrieve the data of the currently logged in user only.